# Counting product pairs in a store whose difference in expenses is less than a certain amount in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the serial number of each product, whether it is in stock (1- in stock, 0- not in stock), the level of revenue from the product and the level of expenses from the product in the store. I would like to write a query that counts all customer pairs (without duplication of the same pair), that the expense difference between them is less than NIS 1,000 and both are in stock or both are out of stock. Show the average income gap (approximately) of all pairs, how many such pairs are in stock And how much is not in stock.

Sample table:

| serial | Is_in_stock | Revenu_ from_the_product | Expenses_from_the_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 27627 | 57661 |
| 2 | 0 | 48330 | 20686 |
| 3 | 0 | 26010 | 861 |
| 4 | 1 | 22798 | 37771 |
| 5 | 0 | 24606 | 8905 |
| 6 | 1 | 48311 | 6433 |
| 7 | 0 | 29929 | 6278 |
| 8 | 0 | 24254 | 8590 |

Unfortunately I am lost and unable to find a solution to my problem.
I was thinking of creating subqueries but could not find a suitable solution

The result should show something like this(Please do not refer to this data for illustration):

| Average income gap (in absolute value) of all pairs | Quantity of pairs in stock | The amount of pairs that are not in stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 10 | 5 |

In addition it is very important that the count be done without duplicates of the same pair

Comment: Please mention your desired output.

Comment: I'm confused too where are  customer pairs?

Comment: Please could you explain the business logic to help us follow the SQL logic of what you're looking for? If you could post a fiddle it would help.

Comment: Hi
Thank you very much for responding to the help
I edited the question I hope it is now more understandable

Comment: @AidaMotay Definition of pair does not clear. Maybe this is the definition of pair `the expense difference between them is less than NIS 1,000 and both are in stock or both are out of stock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with two queries, without a procedure or user defined function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products(serial INT, Instock INT, Revenu INT, Expenses INT);
>
> INSERT INTO products VALUES
>   (1,1,27627,57661),
>   (2,0,48330,20686),
>   (3,0,26010,861  ),
>   (4,1,22798,37771),
>   (5,0,24606,8905 ),
>   (6,1,48311,6433 ),
>   (7,0,29929,6278 ),
>   (8,0,24254,8590 );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.serial,b.serial from 
> products a
> join products b
> on abs(a.expenses-b.expenses)<1000
> where a.serial<b.serial
> and a.instock=b.instock
> ```

> ```
> serial | serial
> -----: | -----:
>      5 |      8
> ```

> ```
> select count(a.expenses) 'number of pairs',
>   avg(abs(a.expenses-b.expenses)) 'average difference',
>   sum(case when a.instock=1 and b.instock=1 then 1 else 0 end) pairsInstock,
>   sum(case when a.instock=0 and b.instock=0 then 1 else 0 end) pairsneitherStock,
>   sum(case when (a.instock+b.instock)=1 then 1 else 0 end ) oneInStock
> from products a
> cross join products b
> where a.serial < b.serial;
> ```
>
> ```
> number of pairs | average difference | pairsInstock | pairsneitherStock | oneInStock
> --------------: | -----------------: | -----------: | ----------------: | ---------:
>              28 |         21362.1071 |            3 |                10 |         15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=225030454da20584abc8bbda4d18f3db)*

Comment: Is one in stock on the condition that you placed it is present or does not exist or is there only one of the item?

Comment: I have used the column Is_in_stock as an indicator of in stock or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in stored procedure.

1. Starting with variables definition.
2. Cursor iterate results of sorted list and check if the following condition it `TRUE` according to your definition of pair.

   `prev_exp - curr_Expenses_from_the_product < 1000 AND prev_in_stock - curr_Is_in_stock = 0`
3. In case it `TRUE` counter increased by 1.
4. In the end I closing the cursor and returning the counter value.

* You can add more logic to procedure and return more columns.

** Usage of this procedure is just to call to stored procedure by its name.

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE A(serial INT(11), Is_in_stock INT(11), Revenu_from_the_product INT(11), Expenses_from_the_product INT(11));
```

Data insertion:

```
INSERT INTO A (serial,Is_in_stock,Revenu_from_the_product,Expenses_from_the_product) VALUES
  (1,1,27627,57661),
  (2,0,48330,20686),
  (3,0,26010,861  ),
  (4,1,22798,37771),
  (5,0,24606,8905 ),
  (6,1,48311,6433 ),
  (7,0,29929,6278 ),
  (8,0,24254,8590 );
```

Query:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE prev_exp int(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE prev_in_stock int(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curr_Is_in_stock int(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curr_Expenses_from_the_product int(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE duplications_counter int(11) DEFAULT 0;
    

    -- declare cursor for relevant fields
    DEClARE curs
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT A.Is_in_stock,A.Expenses_from_the_product FROM A ORDER BY A.Expenses_from_the_product DESC;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN curs;

    getRow: LOOP
        FETCH curs INTO curr_Is_in_stock,curr_Expenses_from_the_product;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getRow;
        END IF;
        IF prev_exp - curr_Expenses_from_the_product < 1000 AND prev_in_stock - curr_Is_in_stock = 0 THEN
                SET duplications_counter = duplications_counter+1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP getRow;
    CLOSE curs;
-- return the counter
SELECT duplications_counter;
END
```

Result:

Counter: 5

Comment: Hi Is an explanation possible?